# Is it correct to use comma before and after the word 'actually' in the following sentence?

Tags: punctuation

So, the sentence is:

> I think we are all looking for an answer from someone who, actually, is a Hawking's student, at least I am.

I want to emphasize on the word 'actually' because someone who is not a Hawking's student answered the question that I asked on some other forum.

How good is it to use the commas before and after the word 'actually'?

Comment: Idiomatically, most of us would say *...someone who is actually a Hawking's student*, where no comma is required (the word *actually* can come before or after the verb *is*, depending on exactly what emphasis you want). And orthographically most of us would either start a new sentence or follow that with a dash, not a comma.

Comment: The positioning of 'actually' can change what it does. And this example doesn't work. Also, what is a 'Hawking's student'? Is 'a student of Hawking' meant or 'a student of Hawking's'? (Or is there actually an establishment callled Hawking's College?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, By Hawking's student, I mean a student of Stephen Hawking.

Comment: It's not idiomatic to say "a Hawking's student". "A student of Hawking's" is correct if the student is/was tutored by Hawking; "a student of Hawking" if the person studies/studied the man and his work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anything, the commas weaken that sentence.  They imply a pause either side of a rather heavily emphasised **actually**.  This certainly gives some emphasis of feeling - in a rather confrontational or disputatious manner - but adds nothing to the issue of key importance to you.

Since the status of this other person (are they a Hawking's student or not?) is important to you, you should emphasise the agency of that.  To do this, it would be better if **actually** and **is** were paired and emphasised together.  Commas do not help here.  Italics would be better

> someone who *actually is* a Hawking's student

or reversing the order of those two words

> someone who is actually a Hawking's student

Both options give a better flow, which sustains the energy of your debate.  Drop the commas, which (to me) seem to diminish and hamper the tone.

Answer (score 0):

You could trying bolding or italisizing "***is a Hawking's student***", and just get rid of the actually.